# Error installing rpy2 in ubuntu

Tags: python, r, ubuntu, pip, rpy2

I'm trying to install rpy2 on ubuntu 13.10 but I keep getting the following error when I run

```
pip install r2py
    Downloading/unpacking rpy2
  Downloading rpy2-2.3.9.tar.gz (187kB): 187kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package rpy2

    "/usr/lib/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags
    Invalid substring
    -fopenmp
    in string
    -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lrt -ldl -lm
    Problem while running `"/usr/lib/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags`

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info

writing pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



"/usr/lib/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags

Invalid substring

-fopenmp

in string

-Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lrt -ldl -lm

Problem while running `"/usr/lib/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags`



----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/rpy2
Storing complete log in /home/sina/.pip/pip.log
```

I tried to install the package from source but I get the same error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fixed in rpy2 2.3.10. (Available on pypi).

Answer (score 0):

It will be probably be fixed in a later release:
https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/pull-request/28/fix-parsing-of-fopenmp-and-similar-config/diff

from here: [rpy2, R and Ubuntu 12.04 - Invalid substring -fopenmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905129/rpy2-r-and-ubuntu-12-04-invalid-substring-fopenmp)